# How to draw a VectorPlot where each component is a piecewise function？

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I want to draw a VectorPlot where each component is a piecewise function in Mathematica14.0,
such as

```
    f1[x_, z_] := Piecewise[{{x + z, x^2 + z^2 >= 1}, {-x + 2 z, x^2 + z^2 < 1}}];
    f2[x_, z_] := Piecewise[{{-x + z, x^2 + z^2 >= 1}, {x - 2 z, x^2 + z^2 < 1}}];
    VectorPlot[{f1[x, z], f2[x, z]}, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

But, I only get that
[image]

Comment: `VectorPlot[{f1[x, z], f2[x, z]} // PiecewiseExpand, {x, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}]`

Answer (score 7):

- `PiecewiseExpand`

```
VectorPlot[{f1[x, z], f2[x, z]} // PiecewiseExpand, {x, -2,    2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Or

- `Block`

```
VectorPlot[
 Block[{x = x, z = z}, {f1[x, z], f2[x, z]}], {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This work :

```
f1[x_, z_] := 
  Piecewise[{{x + z, x^2 + z^2 >= 1}, {-x + 2 z, x^2 + z^2 < 1}}];
f2[x_, z_] := 
  Piecewise[{{-x + z, x^2 + z^2 >= 1}, {x - 2 z, x^2 + z^2 < 1}}];
VectorPlot[
 Function[{x, z}, {f1[x, z], f2[x, z]}][x, z], {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

I don't have the explanation at the moment.

[image]